# Is the following company name in correct word order?

Tags: word-order

Is the following company name correct?

> Irrigation and traffic works construction investment joint stock company

The company aims to invest in the construction of irrigation and traffic works and it is a joint stock company. However, when registering we need an English name for the company but I don't know how to write Da Nang irrigation and traffic works construction. I am completely confused.

Comment: Please never just ask “Is this correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Comment: As a native speaker, you would never know how difficult it is for us to find a sensible and correct way to say thing. That's the reason why I posted this question and asked for help. By the way, like many others who frequently ask questions on this site, I never ask question until I have thoroughly searched but find myself hepless. Thanks for taking your time to reply.

Comment: All questions that say “Is this correct” are considered off-topic proofreading questions. You have to say what your concerns are.

Comment: My concern is how to put this group of words in the correct order. The company aims to invest in the construction of irrigation and traffic works and it is a joint stock company. However, when registering we need an English name for the company but i don't know how to write it. Da Nang irrigation and traffic works construction.... I am completely confused.

Comment: @phuloctoday - I understand your concerns. Let us know where you've looked; whether you've considered other names (and what those possibilities were); and **especially** what leads you to believe this one is more correct than anything else. I think what people are saying is this: We can best help you if you help us know exactly what you've done, and what part of the question is giving you the most trouble. Word sequence? Word choice? Something else? Give us some more information; then we can help you better :-)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it is a 'joint-stock' company is a matter of its legal status and not equivalent to the other words which describe its type of business. I am also unclear whether 'investment' is another arm of the company's business, or whether it is an investment company in the areas mentioned. It seems to me you should say 'Joint-stock company investing in irrigation and traffic works construction'.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i want to say: a joint stock company investing in irrigation and traffic works construction. But we need a legal English name for the company, and normally people would say 'Danang ....JSC'. Our problem is that we don't know how to arrange these words in the correct order. Could you please kindly help?

Comment: @phuloctoday  If the company is incorporated in the United Kingdom it is either a PLC (Publically Listed Company) or some form of Private Company which would have 'Ltd' after its name.